# ASP.NET Losing listbox binding on viewchange?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, formview

Ok so what seems like a basic problem is getting the better of me and my exstensive google efforts have come up short. Perhaps I don't understand enough to ask the right questions.

Here's my problem:

I have a formview control, or rather a series of them, each page displaying entry from previous forms, for a higher level access to approve/edit as needed. So, on form "B", I have the contents of form "A" and the blank part of "B" to filled out...So two seperate fromviews on the page.."A" and "B"

That works fine, the issue is when I change the mode to edit previous entry. So if I have a button or the default linkbutton to change from ReadOnly to Edit I not only lose bindings but any efforts to counteract that have left me with issues when I postback.

***DUE TO LENGTH I'M LEAVING SOME CODE OUT***

On my button I'm using FormView2.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit) to change view, the default link button I've not changed

Bindings on my listboxes are setup like:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    'pulling bindings from table
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM mslToi", objCon)
    objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    lst1.DataValueField = "listing"
    lst1.DataTextField = "listing"
    lst1.DataSource = objReader
    lst1.DataBind()

    'pre-selecting input data from form "A"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [type_of_injury] FROM S2childToi WHERE ID = " & qs & "", objCon)
    objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While objReader.Read

            For Each y As ListItem In lst1.Items
                If y.Text = objReader.Item(0) Then
                    y.Selected = True
                End If
            Next
        Loop

end if
```

In the page load event.

***MARKUP FOR THE FORMVIEW AS ASKED***

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" 
    Width="100%" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource4">

<ItemTemplate>
</ItemTemplate>

<EditItemTemplate>
</EditItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
```

'''that is the short and sweet of the formview markup as requested. It may also be worth noting that it doesn't matter what mode I start in, if I change modes it equals same result'''

That works fine so far...it's when I change view to Edit that my listbox appears to no longer be bound (controls appear but have no content). My thought is that obviously I'm blocking out my code from postback events (I have a reason for this). I can use this code (without the If Not Page.IsPostBack) to force the selections and bindings but whenever I postback they will defualt to the table data, which can't happen, each listbox needs to postback so I can check for a certain selection. So what happens is the user input is trumped. Short and sweet.

I'm sorry that I can't explain better, any advice is much appreciated. If I can asnwer any questions or post code let me know.

Comment: Yes, I have looked for implictly disabled divs and what not, and even explicitly enabled it from the formview down to the control itself.

Comment: Can you post your FormView markup?

Comment: @pinoy_ISF Please review edit above

Comment: Where is your listbox defined? Is it in ItemTemplate or EditTemplate? If it's in EditTemplate then, bind the data when you change view to Edit.

Comment: I've tried this to no avail. The event functions properly but my listbox "toiList" remains to appear unbound. However the way you worded that leaves me to question something. I have this listbox defined identicle in both modes, let me try something and I'll post back

Comment: Do you need to display the data in a listbox when in readonly mode? Because if not, then just present the data in literal or label. Then, display in listbox in Edit mode.

Comment: Well that didn't work out. My hope was that somehow there was some discrepancy from the object name causing a conflict but it's just not working. And if I force the binding and selection on page load it leaves all postbacks trumping my user input..hmm

Comment: I think it would present best to my users to have a listbox, there is the potential to have many selected items or very few depending on circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxReadonly" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxEdit" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Then, in your FormView's databound event, bind the data into your listbox depending on the current view.

```
Protected Sub FormView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FormView1.DataBound
    Dim myListBox As ListBox

    If FormView1.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.ReadOnly Then
        myListBox = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("ListBoxReadonly"), ListBox)
    ElseIf FormView1.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Edit Then
        myListBox = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("ListBoxEdit"), ListBox)
    End If

    If myListBox IsNot Nothing Then
        myListBox.DataValueField = "listing"
        myListBox.DataTextField = "listing"
        myListBox.DataSource = GetListingData()
        myListBox.DataBind()

        ' your pre-select code here...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ha! Very good sir! (or ma'am?). This event turned out to be the key for me. One that fires when the formview changes but not on every page load i.e. exempt from postback. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :-) and oh, I am male.